# Is it possible to create pop up alarm window with Thingsboard when the main browser window is minimized?

Tags: thingsboard

I noticed that when there is alarm event and the browser is minimized the alarm cannot be noticed by the person looking at the monitor until they switch the focus to the browser.

Is there a way to configure Thingsboard so a pop-up window with notification of such alarm event appears immediately at the top of any other open window?

Comment: Sorry for not directly answering your question, but to get an external notification can you make use of generating emails on alarm created? That's the simplest way I can think to do it.

Comment: Thank you @JacksonB,
We already send emails, SMS and other similar. But a customer asked if we can add this feature. as well. I have already received official reply from Thingsboard support that currently this is not available. Will have to invent some method to make it happen, perhaps some browser add-on or something similar may do the job